# Angular 8 Interception redirect with message

Tags: angular, http, authentication, interceptor

The code below shows an interceptor. When the statuscode is 401 I want to redirect the user to the login screen and show a message "Password or username not valid". How can I achieve this?

Because if I route the user to the login screen, will the "return throwError" ever be called? And also, is  there a way to test this?

Interceptor:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError(err => {

            let errorMessage = '';

            if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) { // server side error

                switch (err.status) {
                    case 401:      //login
                        errorMessage = `Username or password not found`;
                        this.authenticationService.logout(); // removes session data (if there are any)
                        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                        break;          
            }
            return throwError(errorMessage);
        }
    }
  ))
}
```

LoginServiceMethod:

```
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post<User>(`https://test/login`, { username, password })
    .pipe(
      map(user => {
        // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        this.toast.success(user.username + ' logged in');
        return user;
    }));
```

}

ComponentLoginMethod:

```
    this.authenticationService.login(username, password)
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(
      data => {
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      },
      error => {
        console.error("blabla" + error);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Why would you redirect user before checking if credentials are valid?

Comment: Well, checking happens in the backend right. If the backend returns 401, that means that the user wasnt able to login, wrong information given. So I want to redirect that user to the login screen and show a message.

Comment: Sounds strange to have that check in the interceptor, I'd have it in the callback of the actual login function. That way you don't have to do anything else but bind the message to the view.

Comment: You should use AuthGuards and CanActivate...

Comment: @Seryoga I am using AuthGuard to check if the user can go to pages beyond the login page. But lets say the user wants to login, in the backend it has to be checked if it's a valid user, if that's not the case I will need to do something with the statuscode 401 right? I want to display an error saying wrong credentials.

Comment: I would create  the interceptor after I logged in successfully and use it only for errors like 404 (not found) or 403 (forbidden) etc and redirect to error pages wich display the error code + message. I dont need a interceptor if im not logged in. Just do the login request and print the error message.

Comment: @Seryoga Thank you, let's say I have a 500 statuscode, should I just route the user to the 500 page and give a message via the parameters? Or should I return the whole object from the interceptor?

Comment: i would route to an error page and print: "500 Internal Server Error Oh no! Something bad happened. Please come back later when we fixed that problem. Thanks."  Maybe this could help you: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81416/best-way-to-display-errors-to-users-who-encounter-an-internal-server-error

Comment: @Seryoga But if I always show "Invalid username or password" while the statuscode could be 500 when trying to login, what then? It doesn't feel very good.

Comment: Show "Invalid username or password" when the server returns 401 on the login page.

Comment: @Seryoga I don't understand how I can compare with 401 outside the interceptor..

Answer (score 0):

The return statement might run. It depends if the code got to it or not.

I suggest you'll surround the entire switch with a `setTimeout()` function to make sure the end user will see your message before redirecting. This will also ensure you are not calling the return statement before redirect.

Something like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
                    switch (err.status) {
                    case 401:      //login
                        errorMessage = `Username or password not found`;
                        this.authenticationService.logout(); // removes session data (if there are any)
                        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                        break;          
                    }
                }, 3000);
```

3000 - this is the time in ms before the code continue.